# Delete pixel in a bitmap

Tags: c#, pixel

Is there a way for me to delete a single pixel in a bitmap in C#? I already tried to look for a solution on the internet but I cant find one.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you mean with "delete a pixel"? Bitmaps are (usually) rectangular grids of pixels with all of them having a defined value.

You can set the color of a single pixel by using [`SetPixel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.setpixel.aspx) on a Bitmap object. This can be fully-transparent, too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is possible to "delete" a pixel, but you can set it to a specified color.

```
// Open your image
string path = "./path/to/your_image.bmp";
Bitmap img = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(path);

// Supporting variables
int x = 5;
int y = 5;
Color color = Color.Black;

// Actual operation
img.SetPixel(x, y, color);
img.Save(path);
```